# Enable verbose output from groovy's AntBuilder

Tags: ant, groovy, antbuilder

Is there a way to turn debug/verbose output on for groovy's AntBuilder? In other words, I want to enable more detailed output like one would get with `ant -verbose` from the command line.

I know about the [recorder task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233382/539048), but this writes to a file, and I want to write to stdout or possibly a logger (like the one provided for [maven plugins written in groovy](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Implementing+Maven+Plugins)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As inspired by [the first result from google](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/AntBuilder) (rewritten for Groovy conciseness):

```
ant.project.buildListeners[0].messageOutputLevel = 4
```

Values are [documented here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/constant-values.html#org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_DEBUG), with 4 being most verbose.

Comment: Works great! Apparently my googling skills are lacking today

Comment: @GreenGiant the magic google words today were `antbuilder verbose` ;-)

Comment: thanks. I tried all sorts of things like "log", "debug", etc. :\

Comment: Thank you Tim, to suppress standard AntBuilder output instead similarly use: `ant.project.getBuildListeners().firstElement().setMessageOutputLevel(0)`