# How do you determine within Ant whether verbose is enabled?

Tags: ant, verbosity

Within an ant build.xml, I want to influence a child process's verbose flag based on whether ant itself was run with verbose enabled. Is there a variable set to determine this? Or otherwise, can I parse the raw Ant command line somehow to check whether `-v` is passed?

Comment: might this be of any use :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232168/is-there-a-way-to-set-ant-verbose-inside-build-xml

Comment: Unfortunately not. Instead of enabling verbose within Ant, I need to detect verbose within Ant - the opposite.

Comment: @Reinderien Was my answer correct? If you accept correct answers people will be motivated to help you in future

Comment: @OlegPavliv I'm aware. I haven't had the time to test it, but when I do I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `sun.java.command` contains command line options

```
<project >
    <echo message="${sun.java.command}" />
    <condition property="verbose.is.set">
        <contains string="${sun.java.command}" substring="-v" />
    </condition>
    <echo message="${verbose.is.set}" />
</project>
```